# Wait for future to complete

Tags: dart, dart-async

I use my postgres database query to determine my next action. And I need to wait for the results before I can execute the next line of code. Now my `conn.query` returns a Future but I can't manage to get it async when I place my code in another function.

```dart
main() {
  // get the database connection string from the settings.ini in the project root folder 
  db = getdb();
  geturl().then((String url) => print(url));
}

Future geturl() {
  connect(db).then((conn) {
    conn.query("select trim(url) from crawler.crawls where content IS NULL").toList()
      .then((result) { return result[0].toString(); })
      .catchError((err) => print('Query error: $err'))
      .whenComplete(() {
        conn.close();
      });
  });
}
```

I just want `geturl()` to wait for the returned value but whatever I do; it fires immediately. Can anyone point me a of a piece of the docs that explains what I am missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not actually returning a Future in `geturl` currently. You have to actually return the Futures that you use:

```dart
Future geturl() {
  return connect(db).then((conn) {
    return conn.query("select trim(url) from crawler.crawls where content IS NULL").toList()
      .then((result) { return result[0].toString(); })
      .catchError((err) => print('Query error: $err'))
      .whenComplete(() {
        conn.close();
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: could you help me on this issue?  `https://stackoverflow.com/q/56505832/1830228` thanks

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on John's comment, here's how you'd implement this using async/await. (The async/await feature was added in Dart 1.9)

```dart
main() async {
  try {
    var url = await getUrl();
    print(url);
  } on Exception catch (ex) {
    print('Query error: $ex');
  }
}

Future getUrl() async {
  // get the database connection string from the settings.ini in the project root folder 
  db = getdb();
  var conn = await connect(db);
  try {      
    var sql = "select trim(url) from crawler.crawls where content IS NULL";
    var result = await conn.query(sql).toList();
    return result[0].toString();
  } finally {
     conn.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer, in scenarios with multiple-chained futures (hopefully soon a thing of the past once `await` comes out), to use a Completer.  It works like this:

```dart
 Future geturl() {
   final c = new Completer();  // declare a completer.

   connect(db).then((conn) {
     conn.query("select trim(url) from crawler.crawls where content IS NULL").toList()
       .then((result) { 
           c.complete(result[0].toString()); // use the completer to return the result instead
        })
       .catchError((err) => print('Query error: $err'))
       .whenComplete(() {
         conn.close();
       });
   });

   return c.future;  // return the future to the completer instead
 }
```

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer could you help me on this issue?  `https://stackoverflow.com/q/56505832/1830228` thanks

Answer (score 4):

To answer your 'where are the docs' question: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/

You said that you were trying to get your `geturl()` function to 'wait for the returned value'. A function that returns a Future (as in the example in the previous answer) will execute and return immediately, it will not wait. In fact that is precisely what Futures are for, to avoid code doing nothing or 'blocking' while waiting for data to arrive or an external process to finish.

The key thing to understand is that when the interpreter gets to a call to `then()` or 'catchError()' on a Future, it does not execute the code inside, it puts it aside to be executed later when the future 'completes', and then just keeps right on executing any following code.

In other words, when using Futures in Dart you are setting up chunks of code that will be executed non-linearly.

Comment: Yeah I read that part of the docs but I guess I just didn't get the part where I pass a future through a function. It makes sense now to pass the returns along

Comment: _"avoid code doing nothing or 'blocking' while waiting for data to arrive or an external process to finish"_ - But what if I actually do want to wait without using Futures and I am fully aware that this will block the whole Isolate? Couldn't I wait on one Isolate like this (which will be blocked during the waiting), while the rest of the app runs on a separate Isolate?