# Is it possible to remove `Future` part from Stream<List<Future<String>>> to make it Stream<List<String>>?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

I want to know if it is possible in Dart to convert stream of object A to another object B, when a converter only returns `Future`. (e.g. `A -> Future<B>`)

Below is an example...

```dart
Future<Car> getCar(String carId){
   ...
}

main(){
    Stream<List<String>> carIds = listCarIds(...);

    Stream<List<Car>> cars = ?? // <-- Is it possible to get this when `getCar` only returns future?
}
```

I could only make `Stream<List<Future<Car>>>` but not `Stream<List<Car>>`.

Comment: Search for "dart wait on future" - https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html#:~:targetText=Returns%20a%20future%20which%20will,of%20the%20provided%20futures%20fail.&targetText=If%20eagerError%20is%20true%2C%20the,from%20one%20of%20the%20futures. (Since something 'future' happens in the future, one must *wait* for the future to become current..)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26856219/2864740 - succinct answer as to 'why'; also see the [the future tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/future/info) info.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks! I was able to solve the problem with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @user2864740's recommendation, I was able to convert using below chain methods.

```
Stream<List<String>> idStream = ...

Stream<List<Car>> carStream = idStream
    .map((ids) => ids.map((id) => getCar(id)))
    .map((carFutureList) => Future.wait(carFutureList))
    .asyncMap((futureCarList) => futureCarList);
```